# How do I write this Raw Postgres query in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I Have this postgres RAW query, I wanted to write it in Sequelize. How do I do this since I have less idea about Writing queries having JOINS in Sequelize. I have made models and Associations.

These are models and associations.

```
TestParticipant.hasMany(ParticipantHistory, {
    sourceKey: "id",
    foreignKey: "participantId",
    as: "paticipantStatuses"
})

ParticipantHistory.belongsTo(TestParticipant, {
    foreignKey: "participantId",
    as: "paticipantStatuses"
})
```

This is the raw Query I wanna transform into Sequelize query

```
SELECT participant_histories.participant_id,
        participant_histories.created_at,participant_histories.previous_status,
        participant_histories.status,test_participants.test_type_id,test_participants.id,
        test_participants.email,test_participants.scheduled_at,test_participants.valid_till,
        test_participants.is_proctored 
FROM test_participants 
  INNER JOIN participant_histories ON test_participants.id=participant_histories.participant_id 
WHERE user_id='${userId}' 
AND participant_histories.status='${activity}' 
AND participant_histories.created_at>='${isoDate}'
```

Comment: At first create models and associations and add them all to the post so we can understand relationships between `participant_histories` and `test_participants`. That way we can recommend you how to transform this raw SQL query into a Sequelize query

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Where is the model schema for both of the above tables. It wont be easier without knowing the realtion between the tables

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't see model definitions in the post I suggest only something like this:

```
// First of all you should correct an alias for TestParticipant like this
ParticipantHistory.belongsTo(TestParticipant, {
    foreignKey: "participantId",
    as: "paticipant"
})

const rows = await ParticipantHistory.findAll({
  raw: true,
  attributes: ['participant_id', 'created_at', 'previous_status', 'status'],
  where: {
    status: activity,
    created_at: {
      [Op.gte]: isoDate
    }
  },
  include: [{
    required: true // this turns into INNER JOIN
    model: TestParticipant,
    attributes: ['test_type_id', 'id', 'email', 'scheduled_at', 'valid_till', 'is_proctored'],
    as: 'participant',
    where: {
      user_id: userId
    }
  }]
})
```